# How to export a big CSV file in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to export a CSV file into a different CSV file with calculations. the CSV file which I am reading has 1,400,000 lines which is a lot because when I tried the same program on 100 lines I got 2400 lines as output.

The problem I am facing is as I run the program, I have zero way of knowing how much the program is done and even if it's working or not. I can hear and see my processor working so something is happening behind the scenes. So is there any way to write the CSV in chunks or know how much the program is done?

**The code of my program is:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv

patents = pd.read_csv('E:/Work/final.csv')

patents = patents[['publn_nr', 'permno_adj', 'publn_year', 'IPC1']].dropna().drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
patents = patents[(patents['publn_year'] >= 1980) & (patents['publn_year'] < 2016)].reset_index(drop=True)
patents['permno_adj'] = patents['permno_adj'].astype(str) + patents['publn_year'].astype(str)
print(patents.head())

patents = patents.groupby(['permno_adj', 'IPC1'])['publn_nr'].nunique().reset_index()
patents.columns = ['permno_adj', 'IPC1', 'ipc_patents']

patents['total_patents'] = patents.groupby(['permno_adj'])['ipc_patents'].transform('sum')
patents['share'] = patents['ipc_patents'] / patents['total_patents']

for v in ['IPC1']:

    temp = patents.copy()

    T = temp.pivot(index='%s' % v, columns='permno_adj', values='share')
    T = T.fillna(0)

    X_t = temp.pivot(index='permno_adj', columns='%s' % v, values='share')
    X_t = X_t.fillna(0)

    T_t = T.copy()
    for column in list(T_t):
        T_t[column] = T_t[column] / (np.sqrt(np.dot(T_t[[column]].values.T, T_t[[column]].values)[0][0],))

    om_f = X_t.T.dot(X_t)
    om_s = X_t.T.dot(X_t)

    for sic1 in list(om_s):
        for sic2 in list(om_s):
            om_s.loc[sic1][sic2] = om_s.loc[sic1][sic2] / (np.sqrt(om_f[sic1][sic1]) * np.sqrt(om_f[sic2][sic2]))

    tech = T_t.T.dot(om_s).dot(T_t)

    tech = tech.unstack().reset_index(level=1)

    if 'IPC1' in v:
        tech.columns = ['permno_adj_pat', 'tech_mahal_sim']

    tech = tech.reset_index()

    tech = tech[(tech['permno_adj'] != tech['permno_adj_pat'])].sort_values(
        ['permno_adj', 'permno_adj_pat']).reset_index(drop=True)

    if 'IPC1' in v:
        tech.to_stata('gajuf.dta', write_index=False)
        tech.to_csv('gajuf.csv')
        print(tech)
```

**And the output looks something like this:**
[image]

Comment: check out [tqdm](https://tqdm.github.io/) if you want a progress bar for your loop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas to\_csv progress bar with tqdm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64695352/pandas-to-csv-progress-bar-with-tqdm)